# Fatal Error : Array index out of range when accessing an array of 10 elements in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm accessing a JSON using SwiftyJson and Alamofire. I've put my products name into an array but when I'm trying to access it for a `UITableView` like this: `product_name[0]`, I receive the error from the title ( Index out of range ). Here is the code:

```
let total_products:Int = json["products"].count;
var i:Int = 0;

for (i=0;i<total_products;i++)
{
    product_name.append(json["products"][i])
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = product_name[indexPath.row];

    return cell
}
```

Comment: how is `numberOfRowsInSection` implemented? In this method you have to return the number of items in the array of the data source

Comment: it's hardcoded to 10 :) I think that my product_name it's empty when I try to access it in tableView func. All my code to unwrap the JSON is in viewDidLoad function.

Comment: Probably, return `product_name.count`

Comment: I've tryied now, my product_name array it's empty. product_name.count equals to 0. So, my tableView func it's called before viewDidLoad. Basically when I'm trying to access product_name[0], the array it's empty. But why ?

Comment: you have to call `reloadData()` of `UITableView` again after the data source has been populated

Comment: I've added reloadData(), I've no error for now but my tableview is empty.

Comment: it must be executed right after the loop appending the names to `product_name`. Have you initialized the variable as `[String]()`? By the way, the variable name is a bit confusing because it suggests a single item.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the out of range error, make sure the `numberOfRowsInSection` returned by the `UITableViewDataSource` is the number of elements in the array.

```
return product_name.count
```

Comment: I've tryied now, my product_name array it's empty. product_name.count equals to 0. So, my tableView func it's called before viewDidLoad. Basically when I'm trying to access product_name[0], the array it's empty. But why ? P.S.: numberOfRowsInSection it's hardcoded to return 10.

Comment: Just add `tableView.reloadData()` after populating the data array.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it !

I've added `self.tableView.reloadData();` in the `for` loop and now my `TableView` it's populated.

Thank you guys !

Comment: It's better to do it just after the loop instead of inside the loop.